# How to download a csv file based on table columns checked in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, antd

i have a table to display the data based on Json. Now i want to download a  table in a CSV file based on columns checked? How to download it?

```
  import React from "react"
import { Table,Checkbox,Row, Col } from 'antd';
import data from "./shared/student.json"
import { CSVLink, CSVDownload } from "react-csv";

class StudentTable extends React.Component {

    state = {  
        checked: 'false',
        columns: [
            {
                title: 'StudentID',
                dataIndex: 'id',
                key: 'id',

            },
            {
                title: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                key: 'name',


            },

            {
                title: 'CourseType',
                dataIndex: 'coursetype',
                key: 'coursetype',

            },

        ]
    }

    onChange = (e,name) => {
       alert(JSON.stringify(e, null, 2))
       console.log(`checked = ${e.target.checked}`)
       if(e.target.checked === true){
           data.push(CsvData)
           console.log(CsvData)
       }


    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>                            
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <Checkbox name="studentid" onChange={this.onChange}>StudentID</Checkbox>
                        <Checkbox name="name" onChange={this.onChange}>Name</Checkbox>
                        <Checkbox name="coursetype" onChange={this.onChange}>CourseType</Checkbox>

                    </Col>
                </Row>
```

i have download a csv file using CSV link. Now i want to download a data based on columns checked?How to dowload it?

```
            <CSVLink data={CsvData}>Download me</CSVLink>;

            <h2>Student Data</h2>
            <Table
                dataSource={data}
                columns={this.state.columns}
                pagination={{ pageSize: 5 }}
                rowKey={record => record.id}
                onChange={this.handleChange}

            />    
        </div>

    )
}
```

}

export default StudentTable

Comment: Can you create a codepen of what you have so far?
What you have to do is specify the header fields as per the documentation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv#0-common-props)

Comment: ok thank u for given reply

Comment: my working example in codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/j3pv3xkv1w